# How to get the value of fieldInfo into a generic base type

Tags: c#, generic-type-parameters, fieldinfo

C#. I have the following classes:

```
public class SomeDerivedClass : SomeSuperClass 
{

}
public class Game  : SomeSuperClass 
{
    public List<SomeDerivedClass> inventory_changes = new List<SomeDerivedClass>();
}

public class SomeSuperClass
{
    public virtual void SomeMethod()
    {
        FieldInfo[] fields = GetType().GetFields();

        foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in fields)
        {
            if ((fieldInfo.FieldType.IsGenericType) && (fieldInfo.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<>)) && (fieldInfo.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(SomeSuperClass))))
            {
                List<SomeSuperClass> superclassList = fieldInfo.GetValue(this) as List<SomeSuperClass>;
                List<SomeDerivedClass> derivedClassList = fieldInfo.GetValue(this) as List<SomeDerivedClass>;

                Assert.IsNotNull(superclassList);
                Assert.IsNotNull(derivedClassList);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I instantiate the Game class, and call SomeMethod the following superclass asssertion would fail

`Assert.IsNotNull(superclassList); //This fails`

while the derived class asssertion would pass:

`Assert.IsNotNull(derivedClassList); //This passes`

I want to get that field as a list of the SuperClass, not the Derived class.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I assume `fields` is something like `this.GetType().GetFields()`? Why are you trying to use reflection? ... But this sounds like a variance problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance.

Comment: If all derived classes of `SomeSuperClass` are supposed to have a list of some type, then use generics to enforce that rule `abstract class SomeSuperClass<T> where T:SomeDataClass{ public List<T> propertyName {get;set;}}`. Just because you can solve a problem via reflection, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: A `List<SuperClass>` is not a `List<DerivedClass>`. Suppose it was the case: you could add a `Game` to it, and the other code would receive an object which is not a `DerivedClass` which it was expecting. You need instead to use `List<SuperClass>` or to use generic covariance along with an interface such as `IReadOnlyList<SuperClass>`

Comment: Forgot to add

FieldInfo[] fields = GetType().GetFields();

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to have SomeMethod go through all variables that a derived class may have, and if those variables extend from SomeSuperClass, call a method on those objects.